# How can I inherit from two classes with the same non-virtual grandparent classes?

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

Suppose I have four classes A, B, C and D:

```
class A {
public:
    float someData;
    float someFunc();
}

class B : public A {
public:
    float someOtherData;
    float someOtherFunc();
}

class C : public A {
public:
    float evenMoreData;
    float evenMoreFuncs();
}

class D : public B, public C {
public:
    float andMoreData;
    float andMoreFuncs();
}
```

Now I want D to inherit only one instance of A.
I know that this is diamond inheritance, which I could solve by adding a virtual to "public A" in B and C, but the problem here is that B and A belong to a library, which I can't change.

Is there any way to do this except from making B a member of D and wrapping all of B's member functions?

EDIT:
As noted in the comments, in this case B would not need to inherit from A, but B also serves as a base class for other classes which by themself don't inherit any class that inherits A.

Comment: "...the problem here is that B and A belong to a library, which I can't change." then `C` does not have to inherit `A`, problem solved. Why not?

Comment: Don't forget semicolons in the code.

Comment: Just have `D` provide these two method: `B& as_B() { return *this; }` and `C& as_C() { return *this; }`, and presto-magicko, problem solved (...or at least provides a means to be used as a solution).

Comment: there seems to be some confusion about what you can change and what not. Please try to make that more clear in the question. You say you cannot change `A` and `B`, which would imply that you can change `C` and `D`, but i suspect the situation is different.

Comment: and "As noted in the comments, in this case B would not need to inherit from A,..." nobody said that ;) If anything so far we learned that single letter names cause confusion

Comment: Given the questions you're asking, I think you really need to take a step back and ask yourself what the relationship is between these classes. Inheritance is not the only tool in your OOP toolbox.

Comment: What I miss most in your example are "virtual functions" if your classes don't have them, then there is NO reason to use inheritance, specially not for code reuse. In fact whatever you think inheritance is usually not the solution. Look for aggregation (and possibly a CRTP mixin approach). Or just use totally independent classes since none seem to operate on data of the base classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem here is that `B` and `A` belong to a library, which I can't change.

Ok, so that leaves the only option to change `C` and `D`.

You could make `C` into a class template which you can then use to either inherit from `A` or `B` - and in the case of `D`, you'll inherit from `C<B>` only:

```cpp
template<class Base>
class C : public Base {
public:
    float evenMoreData;
    float evenMoreFuncs();
};

class D : public C<B> {
public:
    float andMoreData;
    float andMoreFuncs();
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8zvr5roeh)

---

Another option is to drop the inheritance and to use composition. Here `C<A>` will have an `A` member variable and `C<B>` will have a `B` member variable:

```cpp
template<class T>
class C {
public:
    T t;
    float evenMoreData;
    float evenMoreFuncs();
};

class D {
public:
    C<B> c;
    float andMoreData;
    float andMoreFuncs();
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/abYT63vv7)